# Why do the windows on the secondary monitor dissapear when I change workspace on the primary one?

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, workspaces

I use Ubuntu 22.04 with Wayland and intel graphics.

When I connect a secondary screen and choose "Workspaces on primary display only" I encounter an annoying behavior. When I have windows open on the secondary screen and change the workspace on the primary screen, the windows on the secondary monitor disappear (including the home folder icon).

The windows can only be recovered by switching back to the original workspace, hitting super key (overview), switching to another workspace in the overview, switching back to the original workspace in the overview and then clicking on a window to go back to the normal desktop mode.

I have no idea why it behaves like that and did not find other questions related to that.
It is, however, rather annoying. Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue on Fedora. Do you, by any chance, have Blur My Shell extension (https://github.com/aunetx/blur-my-shell) installed and enabled? Because I've discovered that disabling it removes the issue.

I will try to investigate better and I will open an issue in the case.

Hope it helps.

###### Update

I've found an open issue (https://github.com/aunetx/blur-my-shell/issues/345) in the GitHub page of Blur My Shell, there is also a workaround until the problem will be solved: disable "Application blur (beta)" from the extension's settings and you will be able to keep enabled the extension without having this annoying bug.

Comment: Where does the OP say they are using that extension?

Comment: Nowhere @David. Since I’ve discovered randomly that this extension, in my case, was responsible for the same issue OP is describing; I asked them if, by any chance, they have it installed too. Since I haven’t found anything on Gnome’s GitLab related to this problem (while I’ve found it in Blur My Shell GitHub), I thought that my answer could be useful.

Comment: As a comment I would agree.

Comment: I would have posted a comment but I don’t have enough reputation.

Comment: Any update for the same using along with using the blur my shell in ubuntu 22.04